# Haar Cascades Emgu CV C# error

Tags: c#, emgucv, face-detection, haar-classifier, viola-jones

I tried using `Haar` Cascade algorithm for facial detection. However, I got problems in running the code. The error is located in the form and yes, I declared a global variable called `haar`.

Here is my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            capture = new Capture(0);
            haar = new HaarCascade("haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml");
        }
```

The error is this:

> System.DllNotFoundException: 'Unable to load DLL 'cvextern': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)'

I really need your help guys. This is for my thesis.

Comment: You are using a 3rd party DLL which calculates this ? Did you include that DLL ? And maybe you also need to include the 'cvextern.dll' ?

Comment: Try copying cvextern.dll from ``EmguCV\bin`` to your project output directory.

Comment: thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the EmguCV documentation especially the "Open CV unmanaged dll" section [Here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Download_And_Installation), you need to copy the "x64" and/or "x86" directories from `EmguCV/bin` to the root of your application.

If you are running your application from Visual Studio as Debug, it would be `MyApp/bin/Debug/` and don't forget to add EmguCV references in your project.